# Maintaining list of threads and killing them by id

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a python webapp where users send a request which needs to do some background work, I launch a new thread for each request and return a request id to user immediately. Thread does it's task for about 5 minutes, and adds result to db.

In some conditions I receive a stop request with request id for a previous request, how should I stop the thread I had started for that request id ? Is Is it a good idea to maintain a dict of request_id|thread on request and later use dict to stop that particular thread ?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few choices here.

1. Don't stop the thread, just stop reporting the work as done. This goes into what your spec is, but presumably the results not being visible from the API would be "good enough" and you can figure out how to optimize later.
2. Depending on what your thread is doing, it may be easy to add a status check with `queue.Queue` or `threading.Event` or something similar. If you get a status change, change behavior in the thread, potentially returning early.

Whether or not it is a good idea to keep a mapping of `request id : thread id` depends on how you want to address the problem. I don't think there's an easy way to get a thread by it's id, so it's probably best to keep a mapping of `request id : thread object` or `request id : synchronization object` such as the `Event` or `Queue` mentioned before.